# Is the "display" tag specific to Views, or can it be used in different contexts?

Tags: discussion, tags

[display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) doesn't have a description, which would probably help in understanding when to use it.

Should [display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) be only used for Views, or does it have a wider meaning?
In the latter case, should we use [views-display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-display) for Views displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) is very vague.  I would think that some users have probably added it when asking questions about theming or themes (which isn't its best use IMO) as well as for Views' displays.  I like the [views-display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-display) idea as it will actually give the question some context.

Comment: It seems that [tag:display] has been used in some questions only because they were referring to a settings page whose title contained _display_ as in "Display field." I agree it's quite a too vague tag, as it would be applied to everything that Drupal displays.